# A application to open or convert .pub (MS Publisher) files on the mac?

Tags: macos, mac, conversion

I know there are online converters for .pub files, but I'm wondering if there is some actual software for the mac that can natively open or convert .pub files. I didn't see anything posted here already.

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am getting files from a client in the .pub (MS Publisher) format, and I didn't want to depend on an online conversion tool. I want to be able to see the files, I don't care about editing them or saving them back to .pub format. Yes, I realize I can ask whoever has the publisher files to send them in a different format, I'm not trying to solve the problem of how do I see what's inside of one particular file. I'm looking for an easy / quick solution to see what's in them without being connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from apple's support discussions...

> If you want to just show demo files, you could export them as PDF's, or save them as image files. Or you could even publish as webpages and host somewhere
>
> I don't think even in the full OS X on a Mac there is any way to do anything with Publisher files, although there is a utility that will convert them to InDesign.

this is in comparison to the more common `.epub` format for ebooks, etc...  which has several viewing and editing options available on the mac...

Answer (score 1):

I use [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to extract images and text out of MS Publisher files. Depending on what is in your Publisher files, it may be the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

.PUB files are a proprietary Microsoft format for Publisher.  Unless you have a version of MS Publisher for Mac (which I don't think exists), you can't open them natively in that format and will need to either save them as a different format from within Publisher, or use a conversion site/program.

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) as of V4.0 can natively open and edit .pub files. Though I think you cannot save the edits back to a .pub file, I think LibreOffice can only save to its .odg file format or export to a .pdf file.